# How can I get a resultset and a RAISERROR result from a SQL Server Stored Procedure when reading with Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a stored procedure which retrieves some data, does some processing and may detect an error. This test procedure 'dummies' this behaviour:

```
create proc proc_TEST as 
SELECT name FROM sys.tables; 
RAISERROR (N'There is something wrong with this data', 16, 1);
GO
```

I'm using Dapper to query the data, using C# code like this:

```
var rows = new List<Table>();
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    try {
        var command = new CommandDefinition("proc_TEST", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        var reader = await con.ExecuteReaderAsync(command);
        var parser = reader.GetRowParser<Table>(typeof(Table));
        while (await reader.ReadAsync()) {
            var row = parser(reader);
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        // Do something with the rows here
    } catch (SqlException se) {
        // THIS NEVER HAPPENS
        Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
        // Do something else with the rows here
    }
}

struct Table {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This code never sees the error - the SqlException is never raised

If I revise the stored procedure so that it doesn't return any data:

```
create proc proc_TEST as 
--SELECT name FROM sys.tables; 
RAISERROR (N'There is something wrong with this data', 16, 1);
GO
```

Then the SqlException is caught, but clearly I have nothing in 'rows' to process.

How can I get the data AND the SqlException from my stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried using `THROW` instead? You *should* be using that anyway.

Comment: If you want to communicate an error condition and also return a result set then use `RETURN (some number)`. That way you can return a result set and a return code that can be interpreted by your application however it wants.

Comment: @Larnu - I'm interested to know why I should be using THROW rather than RAISERROR? What's the reason for that?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16): *"The `RAISERROR` statement does not honor `SET XACT_ABORT`. New applications should use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`."*

Comment: @Crowcoder - Yeah, I considered this. It does feel a little clunky though; having exception handling for connection and other issues is necessary, so it feels right to deal with conditions which are detected by my SQL checks in the same way, rather than using a different mechanism. That said, I think it is probably is the 'right' way to deal with this though

Comment: @Larnu - I didn't know that - thanks for making me aware of it

Comment: For the record (aside of it being the better choice) replacing the RAISERROR with 'THROW 60000, N'There is something wrong with this data', 1;' doesn't itself fix the issue here - that requires the NextResultAsync() call as explained in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that error and info messages are returned only after the preceding result set is consumed (`SELECT` statement results) and you navigate to the subsequent results (which include the errors) using `NextResult`.

Try adding `NextResultAsync` to raise the error and avoid [undetected SqlExcpetions](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/):

```
do (
    while (await reader.ReadAsync()) {
        var row = parser(reader);
        rows.Add(row);
    }
} while(await reader.NextResultAsync());
```

Comment: Yup. That works. And it explains why. Thank you